# Retaining variable value when stopping android activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've got two activities, A and B. Activity B can be opened by pressing a button in Activity A.

In activity B I have an integer variable which I would like to keep for when I return to activity B from A. My problem is when I press the back button to go from B to A the activity is destroyed.

I have overwritten the onBackPressed method to:

`@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Game.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }`

I can see from my logs that activity B is in the state onStop() after back button is pressed, however, onRestart() is not being called so the activity must be getting killed for memory reasons.

I have read answers to other posts suggesting I use onSaveInstanceState() but when I try to access the bundle in onCreate() the bundle is null. Method onRestoreInstanceState() does not get called.

```
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Log.i(LOG, "instance saving");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("score", userScore);
}
```

I have also tried SharedPreferences but this is not useful because I do not want my data to persist when the activity/application is intentionally destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in understanding the whole Task ecosystem. When you press back button you pop out your activity from the Task, because of that it is destroyed and `onDestroyed()` is called. 
To sum-up I think you are just getting every time a brand new activity. `onSaveInstanceState()` isn't called because activity is killed by user, not by the ***OS***.

Take a deeper look at this developer [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Also I think those two must be helpful : [me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22011959/3874721) and [me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12793395/3874721)!

Answer (score -1):

you can store variables in the app class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html or you can make your own singleton class for this
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm

Answer (score -1):

Starting a `Activity - A` on `onBackPressed` will definitely kill the current `Activity - B`. Instead of starting Activity again just call `onBackPressed` in `Activity - B` and add a stage called `onResume()` which is called when you resume back to Activity B from A

Remove this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Game.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

With this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

When you coming back from A to B, in B `@Override` stage `onResume()` and in this you can save the value while coming back from Activity A.

Add this in Activity B:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // save values here for resume
}
```

Look the Activity Life Cycle:

[image]